# Python3- Geany: List index out of range in csv from url

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming, so I will probably not using the right terminology.
For what I have to do I need to extract as a string an alpha-numeric code associate with names of Italian cities. I started working with a local copy of the csv and everything works fine, but I am facing problems when working with an online version of the same csv.
The csv has 2 columns and it uses ";" as a delimiter.
This is what I have written:

```
import csv
import requests 
comuni_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FloraMarSS/Python/main/comuni_m.csv"
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(comuni_URL)
    comuni_m = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in download.iter_lines()]
    lettore = csv.reader(comuni_m, delimiter = ";")
    for row in lettore:
        print(row[0])
```

The print command gives me a partial list of codes and a List index out of range error, but I don't understand why... Could someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `download.iter_lines()` adds an empty line after `Morsano Al Tagliamento`, i have tried a couple of things but i wasn't able to understand from where that line came from...

Anyway the solution is simple, just add a check inside one of the loops to see if the line contains something, like:

```
comuni_m = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in download.iter_lines() if line]
```

or

```
for row in lettore:
    if row:
        print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split(';') since the content is a str to avoid index our of range

```
import csv
import requests 
comuni_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FloraMarSS/Python/main/comuni_m.csv"
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(comuni_URL)
    comuni_m = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in download.iter_lines()]
    lettore = [ x.split(';') for x in comuni_m]
    for row in lettore:
        print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the data file itself there is a row which does not have a semicolon to split on, it is after value F750.

`'F750;MORSANO AL TAGLIAMENTO', '', 'F751;MORSASCO'`

This is...odd to say the least, because if you look at the csv, it does not show up there.

However, if you check for an empty list when printing the files, you can bypass it.

```
import csv
import requests 
comuni_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FloraMarSS/Python/main/comuni_m.csv"
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(comuni_URL)
    comuni_m = [line.decode('utf-8') for line in download.iter_lines()]
    lettore = csv.reader(comuni_m, delimiter = ";")
    for row in lettore:
        if row != []:
            print(row[0])
```